# Copy cells if not found on the other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Im writing a VBA function to copy data from a buffer sheet if it's not present on a database sheet. It compare the id (in column D/4) from the current row of the buffer ("Tampon QE") and add it to the end of the database sheet ("BD QE") if there is not with an array of id from the database sheet.
I can't get it to work, what are the problems?
Thanks in adavance.

```
Function danstableau(tableau, arechercher)
    danstableau = False
    For i = LBound(tableau) To UBound(tableau)        
        If tableau(i) = arechercher Then
            danstableau = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub copieBDQE()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nblignetampon As Integer
    Dim nbligneBD As Integer
    Dim tableauref As Variant
    Dim msgString As String
    Dim var As Variant

    nblignetampon = Worksheets("Tampon QE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    nbligneBD = Worksheets("BD QE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    tableauref = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("BD QE").range(Worksheets("BD QE").Cells(1, 4), Worksheets("BD QE").Cells(nbligneBD, 4)))

    For i = 1 To nblignetampon + 1
    var = Worksheets("Tampon QE").Cells(i, 4).Value
        If danstableau(tableauref, var) Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            nbligneBD = nbligneBD + 1
            Worksheets("tampon QE").range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("BD QE").range(Cells(nbligneBD, 1), Cells(nbligneBD, 22))
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: "Can't get it to work" is not very helpful. Do you get error messages - if so, which ones and on which line? Or unintended results? Or no results? Details please.

Comment: row 29 when copying `
            Worksheets("tampon QE").range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("BD QE").range(Cells(nbligneBD, 1), Cells(nbligneBD, 22))`  
Error 1004 "error defined by the object or application"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider Variatus's points.

Your specific error is probably due to lack of sheet references. Depending on which sheet is active when you run the code your range might be straggling two sheets which will cause the error. Fully qualify all Range/Cells, viz:

```
With Worksheets("tampon QE")
    .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 22)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("BD QE").Cells(nbligneBD, 1)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, it was this !

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem might be related to the number of records you are handling. i is an integer which limits its capability to some 32000 max. Your loop For i = 1 To nblignetampon + 1 adds *i = i + 1* whenever a reference isn't found plus again at the *Next i*. So i would be growing at twice the rate you expect and perhaps exceed the maximum permissible for an integer. That's a reason why rows and columns should always be declared as Long. In your code there is an extra fault because it examines only every other row.
BTW, *tableauref* seems to have given you a problem.

```
tableauref = Worksheets("BD QE").Range(Worksheets("BD QE").Cells(1, 4), Worksheets("BD QE").Cells(nbligneBD, 4)).Value
```

would give you a 2-dimensional array (1-based), meaning it has nbligneBD rows and 1 column. Therefore the value of cell D1 will be in tableauref(1,1), D2=tableauref(2,1), D[nbligneBD] = tableauref(Ubound(tableauref), 1)
The other thing that struck me is that you don't need to define the complete *Destination* range in the *Copy* function. It is enough to define the first cell. Of course, the first cell is `Worksheets("BD QE").Cells(Worksheets("BD QE").Rows.Count, "A").End(XlUp)`
So, your counting of nbligneBD seems superfluous.
I hope I identified the problem correctly. It's a guess.